# General expanded form for $(a+\frac{b}{c})^d$

Tags: polynomials

$(a + \frac{b}{c})^2$ gives $a^2 + \frac{2ab}{c} + \frac{b^2}{c^2}$ for $d=3$ we have $a^3 + \frac{3a^2 b}{c} + \frac{3 ab^2}{c^2} + \frac{b^3}{c^3}$ then $d = 4$ we have $a^4 + \frac{4a^3 b}{c} + \frac{6a^2b^2}{c^2} + \frac{4ab^3}{c^3} + \frac{b^4}{c^4}$ I did up to d=7 in wolfram and I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using the [binomial theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialTheorem.html)

which says that
$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}
$$

where $\binom{n}{k}$ is the [choose function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). For your specific notation
$$
\left(a+\frac{b}{c}\right)^d = \sum_{k=0}^d\binom{d}{k}a^k\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{d-k}
$$

Comment: Sometimes "choose function" it is called [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Comment: I usually refer to it as the binomial coefficient but I assumed this person had limited knowledge of this as they asked the question